# Error when connecting Azure IoT Suite with Raspberry Pi

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, iot

I am attempting to link my Raspberry Pi to my Azure IoT suite using [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/).

I get these [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjRAs.png) when entering the following code into my terminal:

```
cd ~/azure-iot-sdks/

sudo ~/azure-iot-sdks/c/build_all/linux/setup.sh   

chmod +x ~/azure-iot-sdks/c/build_all/linux/build.sh

~/azure-iot-sdks/c/build_all/linux/build.sh
```

Any help is appreciated, as I cannot wait to connect my Pi to Azure!

Comment: I just tried the tutorial and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've verified the tutorial works on various environments,

1. Host: Ubuntu 14.04, gcc version 4.8.4, cmake version 2.8.12.2, build succesfully.
2. Host: Ubuntu 14.04, gcc version 4.9.3, cmake version 2.8.12.2, build succesfully.
3. Host: Ubuntu 14.04, gcc version 4.9.3, cmake version 3.3.2, build succesfully.
4. Host: Bash On Ubuntu On Windows, gcc version 4.8.4, cmake version 2.8.12.2, build succesfully.

Interesting thing is although gcc(>=4.9) and cmake(>=3.0) is recommended per this [page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/c/doc/devbox_setup.md),  I found gcc 4.8 and cmake 2.8 also works find with this tutorial.

Anyway, you need to make sure you follow the steps thoroughly,

1. Clone iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit and WiringPi repositories, with the **--recursive** parameter.
2. Go to WiringPi and do **./build**. This step is not mentioned in the tutorial but I found it necessary.
3. Make sure you have all the tools installed,

   `sudo apt-get install curl libcurl4-openssl-dev uuid-dev uuid g++ make cmake git unzip openjdk-7-jre libssl-dev libncurses-dev subversion gawk`
4. Build the source code,

   `cd ~/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/`

   `sudo ~/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/azure-iot- sdks/c/build_all/linux/setup.sh`
   `chmod +x ~/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/sample/build.sh`

   `~/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/sample/build.sh`

I've verified following the steps above, it builds successfully on various environments.